# Планировщик задач artisan laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, artisan

Запустил на своем хосте команду php artisan shedule:run, но он выполняетcя только один раз.
Мой kernel

```
$schedule->command('xml:parse')->everyMinute();
```

Проект висит на виртуальном хостинге, подскажите как можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Планирование выполнения задач на сервере

- Выполнением запланированных в Laravel заданий занимается команда `schedule:run`
- В свою очередь её непосредственным вызовом занимается планировщик задач, той системы, на которой развернут проект.
  Если проект работает на unix'е (*с вероятностью 99.9% так и будет*), то этим будет заниматься `CRON`

Соответственно, Вам необходимо в `CRON` запланировать выполнение команды `schedule:run`.

Для этого необходимо знать путь к папке в которой расположен ваш проект.
Допустим, что этой папкой является `/var/www/project/`

Нам необходимо отредактировать файл с расписанием `CRON`'а
Сам файл находится как правило по пути: `/etc/crontab`
Отредактировать в терминале его можно с помощью `nano`

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

И там вам нужно добавить следующую строку

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Разберем что там происходит:**

- `* * * * *`  - это значит каждую минуту, каждый час, каждый день и т.д. (то есть ежеминутно)
- `cd /var/www/project` - это переход в папку вашего проекта
- `&&` - данный оператор говорит, что команда справа должна выполниться вместе с левой, при условии что предыдущая команда завершилась усешно
- `php artisan schedule:run` - выполняем команду `schedule:run` для запуска запланированных в даравел задач
- `>> /dev/null 2>&1` - это мы перенаправляем поток вывода в виртуальное устройство, которое как черное дыра поглатит весь вывод из команды без возможности вернуть его обратно. В противном случае можете перенаправить поток в какой-то лог-файл

> **ВНИМАНИЕ!**
> НЕ ЗАБУДЬТЕ ЗАМЕНИТЬ `/var/www/project` НА ПУТЬ ДО ВАШЕГО ПРОЕКТА!

---

### Планирование выполнения задач на локальном компьютере в среде разработки

В среде разработки на локальном компьютере как правило не требуется постоянное выполнение заданий
Их выполнение требуется, как правило, только при решении связанных с этими командами задач.

И для этого в Laravel есть команда:

```
php artisan schedule:work
```

Пока она запущена - планировщик Laravel будет выполнять запланированные задания

---

**Источники:**

- Запуск планировщика в производственной среде:
  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler
- Запуск планировщика на локальной машине в среде разработки:
  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally