# Laravel отправка email сообщения в определенное время

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Нужно отправлять сообщение на почту людям за 2 часа, 1 час , пол часа, 15 минут до начала определенного события, как это реализовать в ларавел?

Comment: А каком одновременном количестве событий идет речь и количестве пользователей для уведомления? От этого сильно зависит реализация... А еще лучше приведите конкретный пример из задачи..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Планировщик задач artisan laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1438478/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87-artisan-laravel)

Comment: Я совсем недавно в laravel, и передо мной поставили задачу реализовать данный функционал. У нас есть портал где публикуются тендерные заявки. В момент публикации ставится временная метка на определенную дату когда будет вскрыватся эта заявка. Мне нужно уведомлять членов тендерной комиссии прикрепленных к данной заявке за 2 часа, 1 час , пол час и 15 минут до вскрытия это заявки. Уведомление должно приходить на почту. Мне сказали попробовать через планировщик задач Laravel  но я не совсем понимаю как там это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать планировщик [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) и возможно очереди [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues)